# How do i use the internet privileges/access of a remote server using SSH

Tags: iphone, macos, proxy, ssh, terminal

I have access to a jump off server via ssh (i don't have root privileges), from the jump off server i can access the services that i need to use using curl, so i know that access from the server is ok.

I want to access these services locally, im using xcode for an iOS app and through the simulator i need these services to work with my app. Is there a way of using the remote session's internet access from my local machine over ssh so i can make this work?

is this possible using ssh as a sort of proxy?

Comment: _xcode for an iOS app_ -- `xcode` is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) that provides some source code management tools, GUI design tools, syntax highlighting, and easy clickable access to compilers and profilers. `xcode` cannot run on an iOS platform. Are you intending on running `ssh(1)` from your iOS device? Or do you want to run `ssh(1)` on your development workstation to proxy connections from LAN-connected or 3G-connected iOS devices to a third-party machine? Or will you run `ssh(1)` on your dev box to access resources proxied behind the `sshd`?

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear this is through the simulator whilst developing, ive edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tunnel non-privileged ports via SSH even if you dont have root access.

```
# ssh user@host -L<local_port>:<remote_ip/host>:<remote_port>
```

For example, if you wanted to connect to google.com on port 80 via your proxy.

```
# ssh user@host -L8080:google.com:80
```

Then navigate in your browser to "http://localhost:8080/" which gets tunneled to "google.com:80". You can specify the -L switch multiple times for more port forwards.

Comment: so, if i run an ssh session on my mac with this in place, will my client app work as if it were connected via the remote server ?

Comment: You will need to tell your client app to connect to "localhost" instead of the remote server, but yes.

Comment: can't thank you enough for this, if i could upvote 10 times i would, thanks